# Zune Player or Music or Other

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1056/ability-to-select-a-song-followed-by-shuffle-mode-of-the-entire-library) seems to be causing some confusion. The OP is referring to the music player but originally tagged it as [zune](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zune) (I have since changed it to [zune-player](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zune-player)).

It is my understanding that the Zune brand is now dead, so should [zune-player](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zune-player) be a synonym of [music](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) or [mediaplayer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mediaplayer), or perhaps [music-player](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-player) or [music-videos](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music-videos) (assuming music+videos the official name) needs to be created?

There are also a lot of other posts tagged with [zune](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zune) that seem to actually be about [zune-player](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zune-player).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it need to be music+videos but now they change too. Zune certainly is wrong unless it is something about the Desktop app IMO.

Answer (score 1):

In general - yes, zune should be a synonim of zune-player. Otherwise it'll add a lot of confusion.

As for the question - yead, I think that music-videos tag would do the job.